# How to change logging level with Mule studio Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, logging, mule, mule-studio

Mule studio loads the log4j properties file from `...eclipse\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.3.1_1.3.2.201212121943\mule\tooling\tooling-support-3.3.1.jar` instead of the one provided in the project root folder.

Answer (score 2):

The `log4j.properties` should be located in `src/main/resources`, and not in the root folder. You can use the `log4j.properties` file from the jar as a template and change the logging level with `log4j.rootCategory=DESIREDLEVEL, console`:

```
# Default log level
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n

################################################
# You can set custom log levels per-package here
################################################

# Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log.
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN

# Shuts up some innocuous messages if using the JBPM transport
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog=ERROR

# Reduce startup noise
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=WARN

# Mule classes
log4j.logger.org.mule=INFO

# Your custom classes
log4j.logger.com.mycompany=DEBUG
```

Comment: I am using Anypoint studio. I put the log4j.properties file into src/main/resources. I still can't get log.debug(...) to the console

Comment: I'm also using Anypoint studio, I've put log4j.properties file in to src/main/resources, but I still cant get log level INFO in mule flow

Answer (score 1):

I found an article that helped me resolve this problem in Mule ESB 3.6. This Mulesoft version uses log4j2 and looks for config as below:

> When an application is deployed, Mule will look for a config following
>   a child first pattern like this:
>
> ```
> Look for a file called log4j2-test.xml in the application classpath
> Look for a file called log4j2.xml in the application classpath
> Look for a file called log4j2-test.xml in the domain classpath
> Look for a file called log4j2.xml in the domain classpath
> Look for a file called log4j2-test.xml in MULE_HOME/conf
> Look for a file called log4j2.xml in MULE_HOME/conf
> Apply default configuration.
> ```

Just put logj2.xml on classpath ie in src/main/resources. It works.

Link to the article:
http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-3-6-asynchronous-logging/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @BJMyers I suggest you read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/238586). TL;DR: this is an answer.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I'm familiar with that post. There is a little content here, but most of the relevant information is still buried halfway down the linked article. I still think this is essentially a link-only answer and would be improved by adding more detail from the linked article.

Comment: @BJMyers I agree that it can be _improved_, I was just trying to say that it should _not be deleted_.

Comment: @BJMyers I hoped that the second sentence in my post is just as you wrote "essential part of the answer", isn't it? Once again: Just put logj2.xml on classpath ie in src/main/resources.